# How to make LoggerInterface service public in symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I want to have `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` public in symfony to be able to get it directly from the container with `$container->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')`.

I tried the following `services.yaml`:

```
_defaults:
 public: true

Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
 public: true

Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
 alias: 'logger'
 public: true

Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
 alias: 'monolog.logger'
 public: true
```

I can not get a clue why it is so hard to rewrite a service.

Comment: $container->get('logger') will get the logger assuming you have access to the complete container.  Are you trying to access the logger from a controller or just some service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As previously noted, directly accessing services from the container is discouraged.  But I was a bit curious to see how to make a private service public.  I tried what was listed in the question and confirmed it did not work.

This may not be the simplest approach but a compiler pass will do the trick:

```
# src/Kernel.php
# Make the kernel a compiler pass
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
...
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $logger = $container->getAlias(LoggerInterface::class);
    $logger->setPublic(true);
}

# And that should do the trick, you can confirm with
bin/console debug:container Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
```

Be aware that only services which have the complete container injected will be able to take advantage of this.  Controllers which extend from AbstractController only have access to a small number of services.

Take a look at [Service Subscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#including-services) if you need the logger in your controller or if you just want a "better" way of doing this.

Comment: Everyones says, that using container directly is a bad practive. However two points. No one know my situations. And secondly, one was not bothered to declare constructor params on a service which this service actually does not need but it is for its child service.

Comment: If ones really wants to know why I needed, I developed a package for convenient options - https://github.com/mrself/php-options. It has no documentation. But shortly, you declare property like this: 
`
/**
     * @Option()
     * @var CategoryRepository
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;
` and you have repository after class init.

Comment: For the record, I did say "discouraged" and not "bad" because there are of course times when access to the container is needed.  Not sure exactly what your options package does from your comment.  Just for info, there a /** @required */ annotation which can be used to automatically inject dependencies.  You can even put it in a trait and then any class that uses the trait will get the dependency with no further effort.

Comment: `@required` sounds interesting. Do you mean this http://php-di.org/doc/annotations.html ?

Comment: Wrong container.  To be honest, I don't know exactly where it is documented.   
 Looked a few times but could not find it.  There was some discussion [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/21763).  And [here](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/src/Core/RouterTrait.php) is a working example of it being used to inject the router into a RouterTrait.  You can then use the RouterTrait in any other service that need routing capability without worrying about injecting the router.  Bit magical but I find it useful.

Comment: It would be redundant to have trait for each service. DI `@Inject` is very powerful. My package does similar. However I feel disappointed that I did not meet DI earlier. Will try to replace that code on DI

Comment: That is great.  But again, keep in mind that the Symfony container does not support all the annotations that the PHP_DI container does.  Two completely different code bases.  I don't think @Inject is available out of the box.  Not sure what you mean by "redundant".  I only make traits for the more commonly used services.  Otherwise, I just use constructor injection.  But good luck.

Comment: Does this code still apply for 3.4 and later? I've added to my appKernel.php (I'm migrating an old 2.7 app) and verified its run in the debugger, but despite setting the public setting, when the service is next requested, its still in the list of private services. 

**EDIT** - yes it does, I just needed to change the service name to 'logger', i.e. $container->getAlias('logger'). D'oh, so simple!

Comment: Thanks a lot SteveChilds (and of course Cerad ). An other situation where this can be required is when you have legacy code where you cannot use D-I

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps in your case, but in my case I needed a public version of the `monolog.logger` service in the tests to mock it. So I created a public alias of it:

```yaml
test.monolog.logger:
  alias: 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface'
  public: true
```

Now when I inject this service using DI with the `LoggerInterface` class I get this service, which I mocked in my test with:

```php
$loggerMock = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);
static::getContainer()->set("test.monolog.logger", $loggerMock);
```

Answer (score -4):

Using **$container->get()** is a bad practise. It violates many good software design principles.

You should use constructor injection instead.

```
class Foo
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: I down voted this answer too. It's not factually wrong, but it doesn't answer the question of how can I do this. There are times when you just have to do this. I like that Symfony tries to guide you into good design principles, but when you need to break them it's nice to know how.

Comment: @zquintana Thanks for downvoting. You and other downvoters taught me a good lesson. I am super grateful.